# How to read and process a file as keyvaluepair in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to read the below data as key value pairs in Hadoop.

```
name: "Clooney, George", release: "2013", movie: "Gravity",
name: "Pitt, Brad", release: "2004", movie: "Ocean's 12",
name: Clooney, George", release: "2004", movie: "Ocean's 12",
name: "Pitt, Brad", release: "1999", movie: "Fight Club"
```

I need the output as follows:

```
name: "Clooney, George", movie: "Gravity, Ocean's 12",
name: "Pitt, Brad", movie: "Ocean's 12, Fight Club",
```

I wrote a Mapper and Reducer as follows:

```
  public static class MyMapper
       extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>{

    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(),",");
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    context.write(key, word);
  }
 }
}
  public static class MyReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
    private Text result = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String actors = "";
      for (Text val : values) {
         actors += val.toString();
      }
      result.set(actors);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }
```

I also added the following configuration details:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", ",");
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
name: "Clooney   George" release: "2013" movie: "Gravity" George" release: "2004" movie: "Ocean's 12"
name: "Pitt  Brad" release: "2004" movie: "Ocean's 12" Brad" release: "1999" movie: "Fight Club"
```

It seems like I'm not even able to get the basic key-value pair reading right. How's the key-value handling in Hadoop? Can someone elaborate on this and point out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.
TM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem relates to `KeyValueTextInputFormat` doesn't respect the quotes in your input records, and just looks for the first delimiter you defined (comma), and defined the Key as everything prior to that character, and the value as everything after the first delimiter.

So your mapper is fed the following as Input Key / Value for the first record:

- Key: `name: "Clooney`
- Value: `George", release: "2013", movie: "Gravity",`

To fix this, i think your should switch back to just using a `TextInpurFormat` and then delegate the extraction logic to your mapper's map method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But isn't TextInputFormat for reading lines one by one? Is it possible to use it for processing the records of a line individually?

Comment: One more question - How can I display the output of the Mapper? I would like to see how the Mapper is processing the records? Can I do this by standard Java commands?

Comment: @user295338 to display mapper output either disable the reducer, or use [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html). use MultipleOutputs to send the mapper data to a different file before sending it to the reducer. This allows you to store the mapper's data without disabling the reducer.

Comment: Yes it does read line by line, but so does KeyValueTextInputFormat, the difference between the two is TIF just uses the byte offset of the line as the key and the line itself as the value, while KVTIF tokenizes the line into a Key and Value pair. To display the output of a map, rerun the job with the number of reducers set to 0.